# Inexplicable behaviour of the function accepting a universal reference and returning a const reference

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have always thought that the following function, which accepts a universal reference, must return a const-reference.

```
template <typename T>
const T& Const(T&& val)
{
    return val;
}
```

However, the following code compiles successfully with VS C++ and gcc:

```
int x = 5;
Const(x) = 6;
```

The value of the variable x is equal to 6 after the run. Thus, the Const function returns a non-const reference.

To obtain a compiler error, the function Const must be modified either to accept a conventional l-value reference or to be declared as returning `const std::remove_reference_t<T>&`.

Why is that? What rule did I miss?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15):

> an universal reference

No, they're called **"forwarding references"**. The term "universal reference" is deprecated.

---

> Why is that?

When you invoke `Const(x)`, `x` is an lvalue, therefore `T` is deduced as `int&`. Your return type then becomes:

- `const T & = T const &` -> `int & const &` -> `int &`

`int & const &` is a reference to a `const` reference to an `int` which is the same as `int&`. *(In this case the `const` applies to `int&`, not just `int`, as `T = int&`)*.

Comment: It took a re-reading of your answer to see what you meant. Seeing `const int & &` and an explanation that that means that `const` is applied to `int &` was a bit misleading. Can I suggest writing that as `const T & = T const &` -> `int & const &` -> `int &`?

Comment: Vittorio, I don't think "deprecated" is the correct term here. The committee can deprecate language features, but it can't deprecate what people call them (much as it might like to).

Comment: East const is best const!

Comment: @Barry: obviously not, west const got me +100 rep! I love west const.

Comment: This is a classic example of why `const` on the left (west const) is just a recipie for confusion.  Not only did it confuse the OP, the person solving it also screwed up with it.

Comment: @JonKalb They can so.  Nyaa.